# Custom Field in CQ5 Page console

Tags: aem, jcr

When we create a new page in CQ5 'siteadmin' , we get two fields to fill up ("Name" and "Title").

Could there be any way to add more fields here (Say, "Description") which the authors can fill up and it will be saved as a JCR property of the page in CRX ?

Any ideas/solutions will be welcome. I can't think of any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add [custom page properties](https://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/CQ5PageProps.html).  From the linked knowledge base article:

> (1) Copy /libs/foundation/components/page/dialog node to your template's
>   component that you want to add dialog properties to.
>
> (2) Add fields to the dialog
>
> Example:
>
> If you had a page component `/apps/<myapp>/components/pages/contentpage`
>   that has `sling:resourceSuperType=/libs/foundation/components/page` then
>   you would copy `/libs/foundation/components/page/dialog` to
>   `/apps/<myapp>/components/pages/contentpage/` to make an overlaid dialog